# Button images blurry in Chrome, clear in Mozilla and IE

Tags: image, google-chrome, button, blurry

The buttons with background images show up blurry in Chrome but clear in Mozilla and IE.  Is there something special I need to tweak for Chrome?

[image: Chrome buttons]

[image: Mozilla buttons]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're specifying a size for the image equal to the source. If the size being rendered is slightly larger, it will be blurry as you show in your screenshot.

Comment: The only thing that does is make the buttons smaller so the images are off-center and still just as blurry.  It looks more like Chrome is trying to do some dithering. `<button type="button" style="border-radius: 5px; width:26px; height: 24px;  background-image: url('features.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 0px;"></button>`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem and apologize for wasting everyone's time.  For some reason the app page was zoomed 110%.  Setting it to 100% (Chrome's default) resolved the issue.